# Canvas draw black screen before touch

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw black dots when I touch the screen and its work, but when I start the activity for the first time the screen is black and after the touch is going white.I want to be white from the beggining. How can I fix it? Here is my code:

```
package com.inveitix.android.clue.ui.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 * Created by Tito on 3.2.2016 г..
 */
public class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Canvas canvas;
    int width;
    int height;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private WindowManager wm;


    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        getScreenSize();
    }


    private void getScreenSize() {
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, paint);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try setting a background for your DrawingView ?

Comment: Only draw things onTouchEvent method by this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your init method add:

```
holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.inveitix.android.clue.ui.views.DrawingView.onFinishInflate(DrawingView.java:55)

Comment: I assume your surface holder is null. Where do you set your surfaceHolder?

Comment: in `onCreate()` methot when I call `init()`.

Comment: Oh yes, SurfaceHolder has a Callback (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html) object in which you can use to execute code as soon as its been created. So use the Callback and move that code out of onFinishInflate

Comment: Can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

change this

`paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);`

to

`paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);`

Comment: Again first screen is black, after touch is white

Answer (score 0):

in your init() put this 
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Again first screen is black, after touch is white

Comment: try in init surfaceHolder.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: I did it and works but i cant draw dots after that on touch

Comment: than in ontouch you can change the color of surface view or either white dot color

Comment: This is what I am doing in `onTouchEvent()`. But dont work